# Material-ui textfield with label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Can anyone tell me how to make text field with label in material-ui lib

looking for something like this :

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/TextField/TextFieldLabel.jsx

but cant find it in the npm package

Comment: github link results to 404

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve a fixed label by passing in `shrink` as a `inputLabelProp`

```
    <TextField
         id="standard-number"
         label="Number"
         type="number"
         InputLabelProps={{
           shrink: true,
         }}
       />
```