# Creating a label alongside an input using material-ui's TextField and getInputProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, downshift

I am using a material-ui [`TextField`](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) to create an input and a label for a typeahead picker type component with [downshift](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift).

I've seen the [demos](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#textfield), and have got this:

```
<FormControl fullWidth className={classname}>
    <TextField fullWidth InputProps={ inputProps } InputLabelProps={ inputLabelProps } />
</FormControl>
```

My inputProps are equal to:

```
const inputProps = getInputProps({ //passed in by {...downshiftProps} on the parent
    onChange, onKeyDown, disabled, error, label, value: inputValue,
    startAdornment: selectedItems.map(item => ...)
});

const inputLabelProps = getLabelProps({ //passed in by {...downshiftProps} on the parent
    disabled, required, error, disabled, shrink: true, id: inputProps.id
});
```

My predecessor had those inputLabelProps attributes defined on a material-ui [`InputLabel`](https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/) component, but in an attempt to get the aria-labelledby attributes working, I've got with a single [`TextField`](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/).

Printing out the content of the input and label props gives:

```
//labelProps
{
    disabled: false,
    error: false,
    htmlFor: "downshift-0-input",
    id: "downshift-0-label",
    required: undefined,
    shrink: false
}

//inputProps
{
    aria-activedecendant: null,
    aria-autocomplete: "list"
    aria-controls: null,
    aria-labelledby: "downshift-0-label",
    autoComplete: "off"
    disabled: false,
    error: false,
    id: "downshift-0-input",
    onBlur: f(event),
    onChange: f(event),
    onKeyDown: f(event),
    startAdornment: [],
    value: ""
}
```

My issue is that no label is rendered to the DOM. The closest I get is a div with a label attribute, that wraps the input, but displays nothing.

p.s. I've seen [Material-ui textfield with label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996388/material-ui-textfield-with-label) but I don't think FloatingLAbelText exists anymore? The link in the answers is out of date, and not compatible with the propGetters pattern.

Comment: I can't understand properly what you are trying to do and what's the problem. But [here](https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/) is a demo of TextField with downshift on their docs, this might help you

Comment: @VaibhavVishal thanks, I've saw that before looking at this particular problem. My assumption was that `getItemProps` would accept an object with the label property...but it does not.

Comment: You linked to the TextField demos, but have you looked through downshift demo? https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/#downshift

Comment: @RyanCogswell see Vaibhav's comment and my response. I have seen both sets of demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly simplified version of the [demo](https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/#downshift) mentioned in the comments:

[image: Edit Material demo]

The `DownshiftMultiple` portion of the demo used a label. I've only included the first downshift demo in my sandbox, but modified it to use a label in the same manner as the "multiple" demo. The label doesn't belong in the InputLabelProps, it is just a property of `TextField`. In the demo, this is a little confusing to follow because `label` is specified as a property on the object passed to `renderInput` so it just ends up as part of the `...other` object that is the spread onto `TextField`.

If you look at the relevant code for [`TextField`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js) you'll see:

```
    {label && (
      <InputLabel htmlFor={id} ref={this.labelRef} {...InputLabelProps}>
        {label}
      </InputLabel>
    )}
```

Here you see that the `InputLabelProps` don't impact the **content** of the label, just the other properties that affect its rendering, so you need `label` as a property directly on `TextField`.